# How do I reset the audio system when audio can't be heard anymore

Tags: audio, sound-volume

Playing music on YouTube in Chrome did not output any sound. Playing video files with Quicktime and VLC didn't work. I noticed this problem before and it fixed itself after a restart. But I wondered if I could reset a process to get audio back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Killing the `coreaudiod` process might work (it did for me). One way to restart it is to launch *Activity Monitor*, then *View*->*All Processes*, scrolling down to `coreaudiod` then clicking the big `X` button to force quit. It gets relaunched automatically.

Another option is at the command line:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

After doing that and refreshing the Chrome tab - audio output works again on my macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. [Source of idea](https://macpaw.com/how-to/fix-sound-on-mac).

Comment: How often did this work for you? Asking as my experience tells me that at least very often all applications using audio needed to be restarted as well? Please also add the versions of macOS you think this applies to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a 3rd party USB audio device for which I need to do this about once a day - ymmv on an Apple-only structure.

- Launch Audio MIDI Setup, from /Applications/Utilities.
- Window menu > Show Audio Devices if it's not shown already
- Select your regular output device on the left - the one with the speaker icon.
- Click Output
- Change the Format [either way] from 44,100 to 48,000 or vice versa. Wait 2 seconds, change it back.
- Done.

[image]